# An alternate way of reloading a chat after few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, refresh

So I was implementing a chat room. I'll start off with the schema that I used.

- I have a `room` table, that basically stores the information regarding the chatroom like the number of participant, the topic etc etc.
- I have a `users` table that stores the users info.
- I have a `posts` table that stores the posts. This has a foreign key from Users and from room tables.
- also, I have one final table that is to have a relation between users and rooms. So it just has the roomid and the userid from the users who are a part of the room.

Now, I have three divs on page, one for the chatarea, the other where the people online are shown and then there is a text area to post the message.

What I am doing currently is, to have a javascript function `loadChats()`, now this method calls a php file that just fetches **all** the posts in that particular room till now. And the same is dumped into my div ie "chatroom". 
Also, similarly, I have a `loadParticipants()` that load the users every other second.

I am using jquery.post for the purpose and in the end of the method, I do a `setTimeout` in the end of the function. Now here are my questions

Ofcourse i can make this better. Any suggestions? I was thinking of a few.

1. On every call to php, I get the entire chathistory and send it back to browser, ofcourse I can check if the count of messages is the same as it is on the client side, and if it is, then I wont send the messages. But is it going to make it any better? How?
2. Also, making a call to server side every other second seems a bit too much of an overkill. Is there any way to do it like, if some new chat is added to `posts` table, then that particular chatroom is notified and updated? i.e. instead of constantly pinging the server to ask for new request, just ask it once, and wait if there is anything new or not. When that request is completed, it pings the server again for the next update.

Comment: one suggestion: Instead of fetching all the posts in the room, fetch only the new posts (check by last post's id for instance) and append them to the chat box.

Comment: Just add a flag field for each post...that is read / not....if read set to 1 otherwise 0....then fetch only posts with flag 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into websockets (I've never used them with PHP but this seems really promising: http://socketo.me/). What you can do is have the server push any new messages to the client whenever they come in, and have each of the clients push to the server, etc. This way you won't have to keep pinging the server over and over every 2 seconds, and loading tons of data to compare. When there's a new message, the server saves it to some database and then pushes that message through all the open sockets. Same thing with logging in/logging off.

edit: Just looked through the page even more and their tutorial even goes through how to get it set up with a basic chatroom-esque functionality.